# header2 . . . how to use

Tags: file-header

I've just installed `header2` from elpa and -- now what? I'm afraid I can't fathom where to begin with this beast. I'd like to make a custom org-mode header. Is there a tutorial somewhere that can get me going on it? I've only found the original "OriginalHeaderEl" code, which lists user commands such as `make-header`. I do this, and a generic-looking emacs lisp file header stuff appears. Obviously, I haven't customized (created a template?) for what goes into my header yet. How is this done? I saw [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/537/inserting-updating-source-file-header-comments), but it tells me nothing about how to customize, etc., not the EmacsWiki homepage for header2 either. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132104/template-for-an-automatic-header-on-emacs) shows a beginner's roll-your-own, which would be fine, but it's not the same as grokking an important piece of the Emacs eco-system like header2....

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-header2.el) helps you. That is how I customize `header2`. Once I have some time on hands, I can format a proper answer, or someone else can.

Comment: Actually this question did feel like deja-vu. I have marked it for closing as I feel it's a duplicate of the mentioned question. But if you don't feel so, feel free to contest the "close" flag.

Comment: @kaushalmodi I will attempt to use your answer as given in the first header2 Emacs beta question. However, I am not certain where the given "customizations" are located. My first guess is somewhere in your init file(s). Likewise, your `setup-header2.el` is rather inscrutable for me, a beginner. I assume this is part of your Emacs initialization which is called. Also, I'm not quite sure where, how your `header-multiline` is populated. As a beginner, I'm also hazy on how these "hooks" are working. Whatever, whenever you can answer will be appreciated.

Comment: [My solution](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/11010/115) in the original emacs.SE question should be sufficient to solve this question. The elisp code in the solution goes in your [`~/.emacs.d/init.el` file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html). It would suggest that you refer to *my solution* instead of reading my `setup-header2.el` directly. `header-multiline` is a dynamic variable (think of global variable); it's updated elsewhere and used elsewhere. Here's a little [quick elisp guide](http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/files/learn-emacs-lisp.el).

Comment: You will learn more on how to customize your emacs by reading elisp code snippets (this is a perfect site for that), by reading other's emacs init files. Gradually you would want to start understanding the analyzing the packages other write. Then as you start to code your own stuff, you will google more, read more, code more and start learning from places like https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html.