# How do I add text to every new buffer that I create?

Tags: hooks, insert, file-header

Suppose I want to put my name and the date at the top of every new buffer that I create. How would I do that?

Furthermore, suppose I want to use the name of the new buffer in the text that I want to place automatically, where what text is placed depends on a parameter that I specify. Let's say if the parameter is "java" then the text placed will be

```
public class [Filename without file extension] {
    static void main (String[] args) {

    }
}
```

or if it's "cpp" then,

```
public class [Filename without file extension] {
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a function that inserts the boilerplate code you want, at the buffer position you want.
2. Put that function on a relevant hook.

For #2, one of these might be a relevant hook:

- `window-configuration-change-hook` - used when you change buffers
- `write-file-hooks` - used when you write a file to disk
- `find-file-hook` - used when you visit a file
- A major mode hook

But there are lots of other hooks, some of which might be relevant for your use case.

---

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/11005/105) is closely related, I think. It's about automatically inserting a file header.

See also the questions under tag `[yasnippet]` (put that in the Search field).

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the autoinsert package which will do much of what you want although maybe not all.

Comment: You might like to give an actual example.